# How the UUID of a corda account is unique across the network?

Tags: corda

How the uniqueness of a corda accounts is maintained across the network. As far as I know a corda account has the following features

```
               * name (Unique inside the Node)
               * UUID (Unique across the network)
               * Host (which hosts the account)
```

So from above 3 how will a Node ensures that there is no accounts with same UUID in a network? or how a Node generates a UUID when a new request to create an account comes? is there a place in network map to hold the account info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can safely assume that the account uuid will be unique across the network as uuid's provide 128 bits of entropy, and because of this its highly unlikely that someone else will have the same uuid within the network.
2. A new account can be created using inbuilt CreateAccount flow. The node generates and assigns a uuid to this account using UUID.randomUUID().
3. Account discovery is different than node discovery which uses a network map. Once the account is created it is expected by the node either to share this account info with the counterparty using inbuilt flow ShareAccountInfo or alternatively the counterparty can request account info using inbuilt flow RequestAccountInfoFlow.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So there is no check is taking place at the time of an account creation ?